# Move logic like this to the controller or model rather than the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this logic currently in my view

```
<% tools_count = @job.tools.count - 1 %>
    <% count = 0 %>
    <% @job.tools.each do |u|%>
        <%= u.name %>
        <% if count != tools_count  %>
        <% count += 1 %>
        <%= "," %>
    <%end%>
<% end %>
```

Which just loops through some users relations and puts in a , unless it is the end of the list.

**My question:** This kind of logic looks really messy and clogs up my views I know there must be a better way of doing this by moving it into the controller or maybe model, does anyone know the correct way to do this kind of logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a method like this to your `Job` model:

```
def tool_names
  tools.map(&:name).join(',')
end
```

And use it in your view like this:

```
<%= @job.tool_names %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much spickermann this is awesome! exactly what i needed

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of ways to avoid putting this kind of logic in the view layer:

1. Create an instance method in the model class (as spickermann suggested)

This will work for simple logic and simple projects. However, when you will want to use some helpers from `ActionView::Helpers` such as `jobs_path` or `number_to_currency`, a model is not a good place for it.

2. Create a helper method in helper modules eq. `JobHelpers`

Generally you can put any helper methods related to view layer in helpers. For example to share common methods for building a view components.

3. Use the decorator/presenter pattern and put there the view logic so model won't be polluted. Here is some more explanation about the pattern and sample implementation using `draper` gem: http://johnotander.com/rails/2014/03/07/decorators-on-rails/

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer, give me alot to look in to.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single line like

```
<%= @job.tools.map(&:name).join(',') %>
```